# Ordinary differential equasion solution loss

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Whilst reading a lecture, teacher mentioned, that during integration - if you would divide differential equasion by some function - you might loose some solutions to it, but I didn't quite get why would you, exactly?

Comment: Do you mean, if you cancel out some factor on both sides? It's hard to comment without any examples.

Comment: Just like anything, dividing by something that could be $0$ could lose solutions, like in $x^2=x$.  Dividing by $x$ loses the solution $x=0$.